# How to cache text entered in the UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a requirement where i need to enter a text in the text field and when i come out of the view and again open the same view where text field is present, i need the text entered earlier need to appear on the textfield(caching) before the user enters the text for the second time.. Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the ViewController of the view containing the textfield get released if you leave the view? Maybe you should hold a reference to this ViewController that it won't be released and therefore your text is still present in the textfield.

Comment: I am doing the same Thing here. i am releasing the viewcontroller in the dealloc method of the same class where i have the textfield. But i am worried about how to cache the text entered in the TextField.